# WCF client probing to service

Tags: wcf, client, probing

is there a possibility to get in the Client.Open Method, so i can try to connect unsecure to a Service, and if this does not work, to connect secure? 
Just like probing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution to my problem.
The key was to build a ChannelFactory and a IRequestChannel. Then I could build a new factory from my binding and endpointaddress. With this factory I was able to build a chennel which I could open to probe my service.